# Format textbox output in scientific notation if number of digits exceed 5

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba

I'm totally new to programming, but yesterday I managed to program a simple conversion calculator in VBA for Excel. Since the code doesn't really need Excel, I found I wanted to make it a freestanding application and downloaded Visual Basic.

After working one night to migrate the VBA for Excel code to Visual Basic, I finally managed to get the primary code function working.

However, I would like to output the textbox1 result in Scientific notation if the number of digits exceed 5. I tried to use the VBA code directly, and while it didn't result in an error, it didn't change anything either.

This is my VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rates(0 To 5, 0 To 5) As Double, i As Integer, j As Integer

rates(0, 0) = 1
rates(0, 1) = 86400
rates(0, 2) = 100
rates(0, 3) = 8640000
rates(0, 4) = 283460
rates(0, 5) = 2120428.8

rates(1, 0) = 0.000011574
rates(1, 1) = 1
rates(1, 2) = 0.0011574
rates(1, 3) = 100
rates(1, 4) = 3.2808
rates(1, 5) = 24.542

rates(2, 0) = 0.01
rates(2, 1) = 864
rates(2, 2) = 1
rates(2, 3) = 86400
rates(2, 4) = 2834.6
rates(2, 5) = 21204.288

rates(3, 0) = 0.00000011574
rates(3, 1) = 0.01
rates(3, 2) = 0.000011574
rates(3, 3) = 1
rates(3, 4) = 0.032808
rates(3, 5) = 0.24542

rates(4, 0) = 0.0000035278
rates(4, 1) = 0.3048
rates(4, 2) = 0.00035278
rates(4, 3) = 30.4805
rates(4, 4) = 1
rates(4, 5) = 7.4333

rates(5, 0) = 4.74600000000001E-07
rates(5, 1) = 4.10054400000001E-02
rates(5, 2) = 4.74600000000001E-05
rates(5, 3) = 4.10054400000001
rates(5, 4) = 0.134530116
rates(5, 5) = 1

For i = 0 To 5
    For j = 0 To 5
        If ListBox1.ListIndex = i And ListBox2.ListIndex = j Then TextBox2.Value = TextBox1.Value * rates(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    CommandButton1_Click
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        CommandButton1_Click
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub ListBox2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    CommandButton1_Click
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        CommandButton1_Click
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        CommandButton1_Click
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

    If Len(TextBox2) > 5 Then
    TextBox2 = Format(TextBox2, "0.00E+00")
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ListBox1
    .AddItem "m/s"
    .AddItem "m/dag"
    .AddItem "cm/s"
    .AddItem "cm/dag"
    .AddItem "ft/day"
    .AddItem "gpd/ft2"
End With

With ListBox2
    .AddItem "m/s"
    .AddItem "m/dag"
    .AddItem "cm/s"
    .AddItem "cm/dag"
    .AddItem "ft/day"
    .AddItem "gpd/ft2"
End With

ListBox1.ListIndex = 0
ListBox2.ListIndex = 2

TextBox1.Value = 1
TextBox2.Value = 100

End Sub
```

And here is my Visual Basic code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rates(0 To 5, 0 To 5) As Double, i As Integer, j As Integer

    rates(0, 0) = 1
    rates(0, 1) = 86400
    rates(0, 2) = 100
    rates(0, 3) = 8640000
    rates(0, 4) = 283460
    rates(0, 5) = 2120428.8

    rates(1, 0) = 0.000011574
    rates(1, 1) = 1
    rates(1, 2) = 0.0011574
    rates(1, 3) = 100
    rates(1, 4) = 3.2808
    rates(1, 5) = 24.542

    rates(2, 0) = 0.01
    rates(2, 1) = 864
    rates(2, 2) = 1
    rates(2, 3) = 86400
    rates(2, 4) = 2834.6
    rates(2, 5) = 21204.288

    rates(3, 0) = 0.00000011574
    rates(3, 1) = 0.01
    rates(3, 2) = 0.000011574
    rates(3, 3) = 1
    rates(3, 4) = 0.032808
    rates(3, 5) = 0.24542

    rates(4, 0) = 0.0000035278
    rates(4, 1) = 0.3048
    rates(4, 2) = 0.00035278
    rates(4, 3) = 30.4805
    rates(4, 4) = 1
    rates(4, 5) = 7.4333

    rates(5, 0) = 0.000000474600000000001
    rates(5, 1) = 0.0410054400000001
    rates(5, 2) = 0.0000474600000000001
    rates(5, 3) = 4.10054400000001
    rates(5, 4) = 0.134530116
    rates(5, 5) = 1

    For i = 0 To 5
        For j = 0 To 5
            If FraEnhet.SelectedIndex = i And TilEnhet.SelectedIndex = j Then
                TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text * rates(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

    If Len(TextBox2) > 5 Then
        TextBox2.Text = FormatNumber("0.00E+00")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

If anyone can also tip me on how to set the doubleclick and enter key events, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's some suggestions:

- in `Button1_Click()` you don't need any loop and just go:

  ```
  TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text * rates(FraEnhet.SelectedIndex, TilEnhet.SelectedIndex)
  ```
- as for TextBox2 formatting issue I'd go with:

  ```
  TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text).ToString("0.00E+00")
  ```
- but I'd rather keep it in `Button1_Click()` instead of in a different event handler (`TextBox2_TextChanged()`) :

  ```
  TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text * rates(FraEnhet.SelectedIndex, TilEnhet.SelectedIndex)
  If Len(TextBox2.Text) > 5 Then TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text).ToString("0.00E+00")
  ```
- finally, VBA `UserForm_Initialize()` translates into VB.NET `Form1_Load()`

all what above gives the following `Form1.vb` code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rates(0 To 5, 0 To 5) As Double, i As Integer, j As Integer

        rates(0, 0) = 1
        rates(0, 1) = 86400
        rates(0, 2) = 100
        rates(0, 3) = 8640000
        rates(0, 4) = 283460
        rates(0, 5) = 2120428.8

        rates(1, 0) = 0.000011574
        rates(1, 1) = 1
        rates(1, 2) = 0.0011574
        rates(1, 3) = 100
        rates(1, 4) = 3.2808
        rates(1, 5) = 24.542

        rates(2, 0) = 0.01
        rates(2, 1) = 864
        rates(2, 2) = 1
        rates(2, 3) = 86400
        rates(2, 4) = 2834.6
        rates(2, 5) = 21204.288

        rates(3, 0) = 0.00000011574
        rates(3, 1) = 0.01
        rates(3, 2) = 0.000011574
        rates(3, 3) = 1
        rates(3, 4) = 0.032808
        rates(3, 5) = 0.24542

        rates(4, 0) = 0.0000035278
        rates(4, 1) = 0.3048
        rates(4, 2) = 0.00035278
        rates(4, 3) = 30.4805
        rates(4, 4) = 1
        rates(4, 5) = 7.4333

        rates(5, 0) = 0.000000474600000000001
        rates(5, 1) = 0.0410054400000001
        rates(5, 2) = 0.0000474600000000001
        rates(5, 3) = 4.10054400000001
        rates(5, 4) = 0.134530116
        rates(5, 5) = 1

        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text * rates(FraEnhet.SelectedIndex, TilEnhet.SelectedIndex)
        If Len(TextBox2.Text) > 5 Then TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text).ToString("0.00E+00")

    End Sub

    'Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    '    If Len(TextBox2.Text) > 5 Then
    '        TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text).ToString("0.00E+00")
    '    End If
    'End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With FraEnhet.Items
            .Add("m/s")
            .Add("m/dag")
            .Add("cm/s")
            .Add("cm/dag")
            .Add("ft/day")
            .Add("gpd/ft2")
        End With

        With TilEnhet.Items
            .Add("m/s")
            .Add("m/dag")
            .Add("cm/s")
            .Add("cm/dag")
            .Add("ft/day")
            .Add("gpd/ft2")
        End With

        FraEnhet.SelectedIndex = 0
        TilEnhet.SelectedIndex = 2
        TextBox1.Text = 1
        TextBox2.Text = 100
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for answering all of my questions :)  I managed to get the output in scientific notation as you described. The code failed when I tried to use your suggestion for the Button1_Click sub, but that may well be due to me overlooking some dependent code.  I also managed to get the events working, thanks to you and @Malcor here.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the scientific notion with the `.ToString()` method. For example

```
    TextBox1.Text = (0.000000474600000000001).ToString("0.00E+00")
    ' OR
    TextBox1.Text = value.ToString("0.00E+00")
```

You can read more about custom numeric formats [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

As for the events, you can check out [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984320(v=vs.71).aspx) (not VB) but will point you in the right direction for using the 'lightning bolt' icon to select the events you want to hook up. Or you can create a sub which `handles` an event like so

```
Private sub Textbox_changed() Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
 'Textbox change event
End sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) Together with the answer above, I got all I needed.